# How to implement it to skip characters

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

How can I implement this to skip characters like: `! : \ & '` in any position?

```
preg_match_all('/#(\w+)/', $string, $matches);
```

Comment: What do you mean "skip" characters? Regex is only going to seek what you actually *search* for. Can you post sample input and a desired output?

Comment: @erewok He escapes, eg: #test (correct) #!test (incorrect).

Comment: What programming language are you doing this in?

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: @hwnd Works well for what I want, just do not escape these characters ...

Comment: So by "skip" you mean "not match". You have varyingly said that you want to "skip", "escape" and "not escape" these characters. You should take a good look at this question and reformulate it in a precise and clear way, preferably with multiple examples of valid inputs and outputs.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Yes 'not match', I think not express myself well, but I manage to fix the problem. :)

Comment: @nuuby: Then post your solution!

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Hmm, but, It was you who voted negative?

Comment: @Nuuby: Yes, as it happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to use a pattern like the following, depending on the implementation, you should be able to find all of those characters and substitute them out:

```
$teststring = "#!TEST'\&"
$pattern = (!|&|\\|\')
$replacement = ''
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $teststring)
```

Should output:

```
'#TEST'
```

Comment: I just want to escape not just replace ...

Comment: So you want to add a backslash in front of the character? You can probably do so by making your `$replacement = '\\${1}'`.

Comment: Not exactly, I really need is a regular expression to do this ... but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

First, strip the string of all undesired characters.  A regex substitution like `[!:\\&']` ➡ `​` is one way to do this, although there are likely better ways to do it using your programming language's string API.

Then parse the resulting string using your regex.

Comment: example? I am beginner in regex. ;)